# python extract n-columns

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of the format:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I want to extract the elements as:

```
a' = [[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]]
```

I tried using:

```
a' = a[:][:2]
```

But it doesn't work as I expected

Comment: `But it doesn't work as I expected`. Is there an error message that we can take a look at?

Comment: `a` is a python list-of-lists, not a numpy array. Is `a` actually `numpy.array([[ ... ]])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])[:,:2]
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> [l[:2] for l in a]
[[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]]
```